# ejb references passed in helper class or create ejb instead

Tags: ejb-3.0

I was wondering which one of the two solutions hereunder is the best practice?

Problem : I have a stateless session bean VehicleBean, I implemented a method with business logic and persistence of a Car with its wheels , their tires, etc.

```
@Stateless
class VehicleBean{
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   @EJB
   Inspector inspectorBean;

   @EJB
   DocumentBean documentBean;

   public void persistCar(){
      Car car = new Car();
      car.setMake("Ford");
      em.persist(car);
      documentBean.persistDocument(new Document(car));
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
         createWheel(car);
      }
   private void createWheel(Car car){
      // some business logic
      inspectorBean.inspect();
      Wheel wheel = new Wheel();
      wheel.setCar(car);
      em.persist(wheel);
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

I have different private methods that are called after each other (1) create car, 2) create wheels, etc) and I would like to regroup all these methods in one helper class.

Solutions:

1) Make use of a helper class CarBuilder which contains all the private methods from my VehicleBean. As I can't use ejb injection, I want to pass it by reference to the constructor as following :

```
public void persistCar(){
   new CarBuilder(this, document, inspectorBean);
}

class CarBuilder{
   private VehiculeBean vehiculeBean;
   ...
   CarBuilder(VehiculeBean,....){
      this.vehiculeBean = vehiculeBean;
   }
}
```

2) create CarBuilder as a stateless session bean and inject the bean in the VehiculeBean.

Do you see any advantage using the 2)? So having a lot of different beans like CarBuilder, MotorcyleBuilder, etc managed by the container.

Answer (score 0):

Passing references to container managed objects in constructors will decrease readability of the code (IMO). Code becomes a lot clearer if you create container managed resources with dependency injection.

Let the helper classes work with the entities instead and create a new EJB when you want to break out bussiness logic in another class.

Comment: If the only problem is code readability with passing ejb references to non managed helper class, I think I would prefer using jndi lookup in my helper classes.Because if I start implementing stateless beans in every single pattern I use (like builder, or visitor that are used very often in my application), is there a real gain except dependency injection??